# Dual displays, one fixed, one spinning (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, display, display-settings

I have 2 monitors and would like to have my setup like this:

1. Monitor = fixed desktop (only 1)
2. Monitor = dynamic, spinning desktop (1+)

It was working like this at the beginning but somehow I changed that behavior. Now when I'm spinning both of them have multiple desktops which is a no no for me.

Is there any way to set it up like it was before? 
I'm using latest GNOME.

Comment: Probably you want to mention the DE here and version here, I'm guessing it is a recent GNOME.  The solution might be to set windows in the fixed desktop as "sticky" or "on all desktops".

Comment: What is a spinning desktop?

Comment: Spinning - when you can have multiple desktops on one monitor and can navigate through them using keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

With `gnome-tweaks`. See screenshot (Workspaces):

[image: gnome-tweaks/Workspaces]

Comment: Could you explain how this answers the question? How is one supposed to configure workspaces using this tool, to achieve the effect the OP is after?

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7 - specifically CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1511.iso with a full development install
added gnome-tweak-tool (gnome-tweak-tool.noarch but perhaps it was already there)
then

Applications -> Utilities -> Tweek Tool
            Select workspaces on the left hand side
            Set off “workspaces only on primary display” and the dual monitors will spin together.
            I also recommend, still on workspaces, setting Workspace Creation to Dynamic

The above should allow you to toggle how the dual monitors behave

Comment: "the dual monitors will spin together" — it looks like you didn't answer the question.